# create a one line text table with auto scroll horizontally fit div width

Tags: html, css

I need help to create a table which fits the div width and, if it will be larger than the contenitor, automatic add an horizontal scroll bar.
I also want that the table has only one line for each fields.

this is the current code:

```
<div id="RiepilogoDatiSito">
    <table>
      <thead >
        <tr><td> . . .</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr . . .>
            <td>. . .</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And then the css

```
#RiepilogoDatiSito{
  clear: both;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 70%;

  min-height: 200px;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}



td { 
   border: 1px solid blue;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother check this fiddle that's what you want so you are placing scroll in a wrong place

```
<div id="RiepilogoDatiSito">
<table>
  <thead >
    <tr><td> . . .</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
               <tr . . .>
        <td>. . .</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </div>
```

and your css should be like this

```
#RiepilogoDatiSito{

clear: both;
width: 100%;
 height: 300px!important;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: scroll;
  min-height: 200px;
  display:block;
  }

 table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 table {
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid red;

 }



  td { 
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
   }
```

here is fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/a5qe4nvj/
```

Comment: Yes this is what i want, but there is still one problem, the text continue to overlap it self

Comment: sorry which text i dont get it